# Cant insert mcrypt generated string into database

Tags: php

I'm using mcrypt to generate salts for each of my users. But the problem is I can't save it into the database for some reason. It will only insert the "normal" characters like letters a-z and numbers. If try it manually in phpmyadmin it works. The field is varchar(16).

Examples of generated strings:

```
$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

crìüü³`·²¨â˜"Yß
K¦—BAC´fÂÇ‡[µF
ÿ¤æñ©U:ñwôg(El
ú5Î’gê Ho¤W¼‚8Óo
```

Comment: Those strings would require Unicode support. What collation are you using, and have you set the character-set in your connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your field to varbinary(16) and the problem should be solved.  This is effectively binary data and no charset is required.

The real test is not viewing it, but retrieving it.  Try something like and encrypt-insert-retrieve-decrpyt-display test with the field change and all should be well.